# Accessing Flutter callkit Incoming Calls Params

Tags: flutter

am at the moment making use of this particular flutter package for my project but I can't access the params, please I really need your help

```
flutter_callkit_incoming: ^1.0.0+8
```

when am to receive an incoming call I use the below code

```
    this._currentUuid = _uuid.v4();
    var params = <String, dynamic>{
      'id': _currentUuid,
      'nameCaller': data.fromFullName,
      'appName': 'Prayer Buddy',
      'avatar': data.fromImage,
      'handle': 'Prayer Partner Calling',
      'type': type,
      'duration': 30000,
      'extra': <String, dynamic>{'userId': '1a2b3c4d'},
      'headers': <String, dynamic>{'apiKey': 'Abc@123!', 'platform': 'flutter'},
      'android': <String, dynamic>{
        'isCustomNotification': true,
        'isShowLogo': false,
        'ringtonePath': 'ringtone_default',
        'backgroundColor': '#0955fa',
        'backgroundUrl': data.toImage,
        'actionColor': '#4CAF50'
      },
      'ios': <String, dynamic>{
        'iconName': 'AppIcon40x40',
        'handleType': 'generic',
        'supportsVideo': true,
        'maximumCallGroups': 2,
        'maximumCallsPerCallGroup': 1,
        'audioSessionMode': 'default',
        'audioSessionActive': true,
        'audioSessionPreferredSampleRate': 44100.0,
        'audioSessionPreferredIOBufferDuration': 0.005,
        'supportsDTMF': true,
        'supportsHolding': true,
        'supportsGrouping': false,
        'supportsUngrouping': false,
        'ringtonePath': 'Ringtone.caf'
      }
    };
    await FlutterCallkitIncoming.showCallkitIncoming(params);
```

on the `FlutterCallkitIncoming.onEvent.listen((event)` function am trying to access the params sent via the `showCallkitIncoming(params)`

so i did a print of the event `print(event)` the output was below

```
{ event: com.hiennv.flutter_callkit_incoming.ACTION_CALL_ENDED, body: {duration: 30000, extra: {userId: 1a2b3c4d}, uuid: 1fa5d670-5698-40fa-8705-bd794304fa96, avatar: http://arome.joons-me.com/user_img/james/images/image_picker_F27FD117-E882-4C51-9143-943E3BF4A8CF-24547-00000899F347179A.jpg, type: 0, nameCaller: James Amadin, handle: Prayer Partner Calling, appName: Prayer Buddy, ios: {supportsHolding: true, audioSessionPreferredIOBufferDuration: 0.005, supportsDTMF: true, maximumCallGroups: 2, includesCallsInRecents: true, audioSessionPreferredSampleRate: 44100.0, iconName: AppIcon40x40, supportsVideo: true, supportsGrouping: false, audioSessionActive: true, audioSessionMode: default, maximumCallsPerCallGroup: 1, supportsUngrouping: false, handleType: generic, ringtonePath: Ringtone.caf}} }
```

I want to access the extra from the return JSON, please how do I do that?

but when i tried to access it via the below code

```
try {
          dynamic myMap = json.decode(event!.body);
          if (myMap is! Map<String, dynamic>) throw FormatException();

          final message = myMap['extra'];
          print('1message == ${message}');
        } catch (error) {
          print('JSON is in the wrong format');
        }
```

I got `JSON is in the wrong format`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve it by the following code

```
        print(event!.body['extra']['userId']);
        print(event.body['extra']['to_user']);
        print(event.body['extra']['from_user']);
```